# Loop boolean: Unequal to NA

Tags: arrays, r, loops, boolean

I want to count the values in an array which are not "NA".

E.g. I have

```
array<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,4,-5.5463)
```

I thought this would work, but it does not:

```
counter<-0
for(i in 1:length(array)){
if(array[i]!=na){
counter<-counter+1
}
}
```

How can I count the values in this array, which are not "NA"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `is.na` and `sum`. The `!` represents "not":

```
> sum(!is.na(array))
[1] 2
```

You can also use `table`, as in:

```
> table(is.na(array))

FALSE  TRUE 
    2     5
```

Or, as @Arun suggests in the comments:

```
> length(na.omit(array))
[1] 2
```

Comment: alternatively, `length(na.omit(array))`